# Replace Semantic UI's Tab with an SVG

Tags: html, css, reactjs, svg, semantic-ui

I'm using [Tab from Semantic UI](https://semantic-ui.com/modules/tab.html) for some tables.

The problem is that the design of it should look different and I've got an SVG for that: https://svgur.com/s/Nnu

And this is the code:

```
const clientsTab = (
  <ContentContainer>
    <div className="clients-table">
      <div className="clients-table-utils">
        <SearchBox
          placeholder="Search client"
          onChange={this.searchHandler}
        />
        <Dropdown
          className="hello-dropdown"
          placeholder="Company"
        />
        <Dropdown
          className="hello-dropdown"
          placeholder="Turnover"
        />
        <Dropdown
          className="hello-dropdown"
          placeholder="Status"
        />
      </div>
      <GenericTable
        headers={headers}
        rows={rows}
        entityName="clients"
        idList={idList}
      />
    </div>
  </ContentContainer>
);

const panes = [
  {
    menuItem: 'Clients',
    render: () => <Tab.Pane>{clientsTab}</Tab.Pane>,
  },
];

return (
  <Layout>
      <TabContainer panes={panes} />
  </Layout>
);
```

TabContainer is a simple component which looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Tab } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import './TabContainer.scss';

export default class TabContainer extends React.PureComponent {
  render() {
    const { panes } = this.props;
    return <Tab panes={panes} />;
  }
}
```

And the final resut:

[image]

I don't know if it is possible to replace the Tab with the SVG. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could wrap the svg as an image inside a `Menu.Item` component like this:

```
const panes = [
  {
    menuItem: (
      <Menu.Item
        key="Tab 1"
        style={{
          display: 'block',
          background:
            'url(https://svgshare.com/i/Nnu.svg) left center no-repeat',
          backgroundSize: 'cover',
          textAlign: 'center',
          minWidth: 300,
          borderColor: 'transparent',
        }}>
        <p>Tab One</p>
      </Menu.Item>
    ),
    render: () => // The content you want to render...,
  }
];
```

So this approach makes your svg the background image for each menu item.

Be sure to import `Menu` from `'semantic-ui-react'`.

Comment: so you're using this https://react.semantic-ui.com/collections/menu/ ?